# python 3.x execute script with linked scripts ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, cron

I have created certain folders and files structure to make my project easier on maintain and flexible over time.

I have store these bunch of folders and python scripts in this form:

`/home/ubuntu/main_folder` : within this folder I have the schema:

```
     |-main_foler
     |
     |-module1
     |---script.py
     |
     |configetl
     |---config.py
     |
     |process.sh
```

I'm looking forward to executing the script stored in the folder `module1` under the name `script.py` with the executable script `process.sh`:

```
     #!/bin/sh
     cd /home/ubuntu/main_folder &&

     python3 module1/script.py
```

The problem comes up when the script is executed because is using a bunch of methods coming from a script stored in the folder called `configetl`.

> ```
>         error: File "module1/script.py", line 4, in <module>
>           from configetl.config import *
>         ImportError: No module named 'configetl'
> ```

How should I set properly my script `sh` to avoid this and schedule this script automatically in a cron?

thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `script.py` probably can't access the `config.py`, because the directory `configetl` is not in `script.py`'s PYTHONPATH.

You could test that by printing the `sys.path` list in your `script.py` when called from the `process.sh` script.

```
# Inside your script.py before calling any config functions
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The output should be similar to this:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

To include the `configetl` directory to your PYTHONPATH and make it visible to the `script.py`, you have to append the path to the `configetl` to the `sys.path` list:

```
# Inside your script.py before calling any config functions
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

This will append the entire upper level directory to your PYTHONPATH.

If you'd like to add only the `configetl` directory to your PYTHONPATH, you could do:

```
# Inside your script.py before calling any config functions
import sys
sys.path.append('../configetl')
```

This will require small changes in the way you import the `config.py` module.
You will have to import it directly, without its parent directory name e.g.

```
from config import *
```

P.S. Using the star symbol to import everything from a python module is considered a bad practice. You should either import the entire module `import config` or list the objects you'd like to import from that module e.g. `from config import function_one, function_two`